# Why cannot use if statement in AppDelegate?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios13, swift5

[image]

why I cannot pass the constant in if statement?

```
 if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape{
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "landscape", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "landscape")
    }else{
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
    }
    

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
```

Comment: declare before hand the existence of initialViewController. Or use a computed property.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Check out [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should add the code as text instead of the screenshot.

Comment: Learn what scope is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert the error line inside the if else block as of scope

```
if { 
  let initialViewController = //// 
  self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
}
else { 
  let initialViewController = //// 
  self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
}
```

OR

```
var initialViewController:UIViewController!
if { 
  initialViewController = ////
}
else { 
  initialViewController = ////
}
// use it here
```

Comment: I have tried this, but once I did it, this function would not executed

Comment: Why `var` and implicit unwrapped optional? The code works also with `let` and without the exclamation mark.

Answer (score 0):

The `initialViewController` is only available within the scope of the `if else` block so you need to declare the `initialViewController` before the `if else` block begin and set `initialViewController` property within the block and later use it as required.

```
let initialViewController: UIViewController
if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "landscape", bundle: nil)
    initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "landscape")
} else {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
}
window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
```

Note: You should probably do more research on scope in programming.

Comment: Why `var` and implicit unwrapped optional? The code works also with `let` and without the exclamation mark.

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at the error Swift is reporting: it’s unable to find the variable with the name `initialViewController` in this part of the code.

Variables are only available in the scope of the block in which they are created. In other words, you need to lift the `initialViewController` declaration out of the `if` statement if you want to use it somewhere else outside of the `if` statement. You can do this by making it a `var` instead:

```swift
// Let Swift know that we’re going to make this a UIViewController
var initialViewController: UIViewController
if condition {
  // Now, initialViewController has been instantiated; it just needs a value
  initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "landscape")
} else {
  initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "portrait")
}

// We can safely use it outside of the if statement, but it may need unwrapping since it was declared as a var 
self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController!
```

Note that copy/pasting this exact code won’t work since I haven’t defined the `storyboard` or `condition` variables: see if you can change your current code to fix the issue the way I’ve described here!